# SQL: Can I write query with multiple columns when one column has a max/count subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

Beginner here.  I have written the following SQL statement and returns the records no problem.

```
SELECT COUNT(MAX(doc_line_num)) AS "TOTAL RECS"
FROM C_LAB
WHERE COMP_CODE = 'P1' AND OP_CODE = 'RMARTINEZ'
GROUP BY DOC_NUM
```

My question is.. Can I write the same query with multiple columns?  for example:

```
SELECT OP_CODE, COUNT(MAX(doc_line_num)) AS "TOTAL REC"
FROM C_LAB
WHERE COMP_CODE = 'P1' AND OP_CODE = 'CHRISTIANMONTALVO'
GROUP BY OP_CODE, DOC_NUM
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error [937] [42000]: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Is this not possible? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you are using a shortcut that Oracle offers. This

```
SELECT COUNT(MAX(doc_line_num)) AS "TOTAL RECS"
FROM c_lab
WHERE comp_code = 'P1' AND op_code = 'RMARTINEZ'
GROUP BY doc_num;
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT COUNT(max_doc_line_num) AS "TOTAL RECS"
FROM
(
  SELECT doc_num, MAX(doc_line_num) AS max_doc_line_num
  FROM c_lab
  WHERE comp_code = 'P1' AND op_code = 'RMARTINEZ'
  GROUP BY doc_num
);
```

and eventually counts the doc nums that have a doc_line_num.

You could also have written this as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT doc_num) AS "TOTAL RECS"
FROM c_lab
WHERE comp_code = 'P1' AND op_code = 'RMARTINEZ' AND doc_line_num IS NOT NULL;
```

Your second query is equivalent to

```
SELECT op_code, COUNT(max_doc_line_num) AS "TOTAL RECS"
FROM
(
  SELECT op_code, doc_num, MAX(doc_line_num) AS max_doc_line_num
  FROM c_lab
  WHERE comp_code = 'P1' AND op_code = 'CHRISTIANMONTALVO'
  GROUP BY op_code, doc_num
);
```

which is invalid, because in the main query you aggregate (`COUNT(max_doc_line_num)`), but also select the op_code for which a `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregation is missing.

Having said this, you *may* be looking for this:

```
SELECT op_code, COUNT(max_doc_line_num) AS "TOTAL RECS"
FROM
(
  SELECT op_code, doc_num, MAX(doc_line_num) AS max_doc_line_num
  FROM c_lab
  WHERE comp_code = 'P1' AND op_code = 'CHRISTIANMONTALVO'
  GROUP BY op_code, doc_num
)
GROUP BY op_code
ORDER BY op_code;
```

But maybe you want something completely different. I don't know. My advice: Don't use Oracle's shortcut to aggregate all aggregated rows again without using a subquery. Use a subquery, so the intention is clear and such syntax errors don't happen.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your detailed reply.  This is what I was looking for.